# if $ 0 < y < 1$ show $y^n \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ & if $ y > 1 $ then $y^{\frac{1}{n}} \rightarrow 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> i) if $ 0 < y < 1$ show $y^n \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$
>
> ii) if $ y > 1 $ then $y^{\frac{1}{n}} \rightarrow 1$

I know it is not practice to ask two questions at once, but I figured since they are of similar ilk then it would be more helpful to combine them.

**Attempt i)**

I am already aware of one form of establishing this convergence by using the Monotone Convergence theorem. Our professor suggested another way to establish the convergence and I was trying to do it in that fashion.

*Proof:*

By the Archimedian property of the real numbers we know there exists a $p \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0 < y < \frac{p}{p+1} < 1$. So it would be enough to show that: $$\Bigg(\frac{p}{p+1}\Bigg)^n \rightarrow 0$$

and then conclude by the squeeze theorem: $$y^n \rightarrow 0$$

I am trying to prove this using the definition of a limit of a sequence, so after expanding using the binomial theorem what I am trying to show is:  $$\forall \epsilon >0, \ \exists \ N \in \mathbb{N} \ s.t.\ n \geq N \Rightarrow \Bigg| \frac{p^n}{p^n +np^{n-1} + \ldots + 1} - 0 \Bigg| < \epsilon$$

Notice: $p^n +np^{n-1} + \ldots + 1 > p^n + 1$..........

This is where I get stuck, I am trying to produce a N to satisfy my definition. I thought of possibly using logarithms but that was not fruitful. I am probably missing some simple trick, but alas I have not figured it out. What am I missing here?

**Attempt ii)**

For this question I want to use the Monotone convergence theorem to establish the result. The difficulty I am having is actually showing that $$y^{\frac{1}{n}} > y^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$

Apparently by the ordered field axioms this already stands, but I don't recall establishing this result. If that is the case then It would be monotonically decreasing. But I don't think we've established this and I want to know how. What am I missing here?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: For part $(b)$, $y^{1+\frac 1n}\ =y.y^{\frac 1n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For i),

$$\Bigg| \frac{p^n}{p^n +np^{n-1} + \ldots + 1} - 0 \Bigg| < \Bigg| \frac{p^n}{p^n +np^{n-1}} \Bigg| = \Bigg| \frac{1}{1 +\frac{n}{p}} \Bigg|$$

For ii), since $y>0$, if not then
$${(y^{\frac{1}{n}})}^{n(n+1)} \leq {(y^{\frac{1}{n+1}})}^{n(n+1)}$$
$$y^{n+1} \leq y^n$$
which is clearly impossible with $y>1$. Is this sufficient?

As an alternative way to do ii), write $y^{\frac{1}{n}}=1+\delta_n$. It suffices to show that $\delta_n \rightarrow 0$. By Bernoulli's inequality, $y=(1+\delta_n)^n \geq 1+n\delta_n$. For here $y$ serves as an upper bound the proof is finished.

This should be one of the standard ways for such limit.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved by elementary method without invoking transcendental
functions like $\ln$ or $\exp$. I try part (i): Let $y\in(0,1)$. Define $a=\frac{1}{y}-1>0$.
Then $y=\frac{1}{1+a}$. Observe that $(1+a)^{n}\geq1+na$, so $0\leq y^{n}\leq\frac{1}{1+na}\rightarrow0$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$. By squeeze theorem, it follows that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y^{n}=0$.

/////////////////////////////////////

For part (ii). Let $y>1.$ For each $n$, let $x_{n}=y^{\frac{1}{n}}-1>0$.
We have $y=(1+x_{n})^{n}\geq1+nx_{n}\geq nx_{n}$. It follows that
$0\leq x_{n}\leq\frac{y}{n}$. Therefore $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=0$
and hence $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}y^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Should this be your third attempt?** We have $\ln(y)<0$ for $0<y<1$ and $\ln(y)>0$ for $y>1$. So for the first case

$$y^n=\exp(n\ln(y))\xrightarrow{n\to \infty}{0}\:\text{since}\; n\ln(y)\to-\infty$$
The second case is quite similar and I leave it for you.

Comment: Using exponents and logarithms to calculate limits of sequences like $y^n?$

Comment: Why not if it gives a short answer?

Comment: I just think it's a concept which is typically introduced later on, and it's thus I feel it's not the most appropriate method. Of course, there's nothing wrong with it; just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

For part $(a)$, we have that $$\left|\frac{p^n}{(p+1)^n}\right|\lt\left|\frac{p^n}{p^n+np^{n-1}}\right|=\left|\frac1{1+\frac np}\right|$$

Given $\epsilon\gt 0$, take $N\gt p\left(\frac 1\epsilon-1\right)$, and we're done.

Comment: So I took the wrong expression....thank you.